# What electrical component serves or can serve this function?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ac, waveform

I was thinking about what diodes can do to AC current, how they can be used to rectify alternating current by only letting it pass in one direction, so only the positive part of the wave or the negative part will pass.  What I'm curious is if there's a component or a type of circuit which will only let current through or let more current through if the voltage is increasing or decreasing.  So it would pass the portion of the wave from the peak to the trough, but not from the trough to the peak (the decreasing voltage but not the increasing voltage).

Comment: Yes there is a way to make a switch do this comparing phase shift from a  LPF.  What other specs do you have?

Comment: Surely a circuit can do it. Increasing/decreasing = derivative is positive/negative. So make a differentiator circuit, and make it control some kind of switch. Some delay might occur though...

Comment: dv/dt amplifies noise sensitivity.

Comment: It's called synchronous gating for want of a better term.

Comment: You also need to specify what you want the output to do when it's not falling.

Comment: For some definitions of what you want, a diode and an R-C network can do it; see "envelope detector".

Comment: @Tom: (1) What voltage range? (2) + only or +/-? (3) How much current? (4) What frequency? The answer depends on all of these.

Comment: @Trevor_G I should've commented about that sooner, but I was thinking that it would just flow through a different path in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy with opamps. Start off with a differentiator amplifier, then a comparator.

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_7.html

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html